# How to convert an array of binary numbers to a single binary number?

Tags: c

I did a program that accepts two decimal numbers and I want my program to convert all decimal numbers that are in an interval between those two numbers (included) into a binary numbers and than to print them.

Works like that:

```
Entrance interval: 1   5 //input

1 // output
10
11
100
101
```

I want my function to accept a decimal number from a main function and than convert it to a binary number and than return it as a single binary number so that I could print it in the main function. Here is my program that I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//function for converting to binary:
int decToBinary(int number_in_interval)
{
    int binaryNum[32];
    int a = 0;
    while (number_in_interval > 0)
    {
        binaryNum[a] = number_in_interval % 2;
        number_in_interval = number_in_interval / 2;
        a++;
    }
    for(int j = a - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
    {                               
        binaryNum[j];
    }
    return binaryNum;
}

//main function
int main ()
{
    int HI;
    int LO;
    char X[200]={0};
    char test_if_l_c[] = {'c','l'};

    printf("Entrence interval:\n");
    scanf("%s%d%d", X, &LO, &HI); 

    if ( X[0] != test_if_l_c[0] && X[0] != test_if_l_c[1] || X[1] != 0 || X[2] != 0 || X[3] != 0 || X[4] != 0 || HI <= LO || HI == 0 || LO == 0) 
    {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 1;   
    }

    int i;
    int num = HI - LO + 1;
    int count_in_interval = 0;
    int LO_ = LO;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            count_in_interval = count_in_interval + 1; 
        }

    for(int u = 0; u < pocet_interval ; u++)
    {
        int number_in_int = LO_ + u;
        printf("%d\n", decToBinary(number_in_int)); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since I am a beginner, could you please help me to make that work? If there is any easier way to do that, I would be really happy for that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the contents of the `binaryNum` array? Do you do mean that you want to convert the contents of the array into a digit-by-digit copy as an `int`? If the latter, then remember that `int` is commonly a signed 32-bit type, which can have at most 10 digits, and your binary number needs 32 digits.

Comment: If this method would work, than yes. How to return a binaryNum array?

Comment: You can't really return an array. You could return a pointer to its first element (arrays generally and frequently decay to pointers to their first element) but that would lead to other problems (as the returned pointer would be to an array that cease to exist immediately once you return). A better solution would be to pass the array into the function as an argument.

Comment: You would never store binary digits with `int [32]`. It'd forget all about this function and instead start to ponder what binary numbers _are_ and why they are relevant in C programming. Because it turns out that _all_ numbers in your program are already in binary, so "converting to/from binary" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: let's say your base number is `42`. Do you want to "send" `101010` (one hundred one thousand and ten) to `main()`? Send the string `"101010"`? Send (if it existed) `0b101010` (same as `42`)?

Comment: I would also recommend that you think of the bitwise operations needed to extract a single bit from `number`. Because then it would become easier to set the corresponding element directly in the array so you don't have to reverse it.

Comment: I made my question now more general since what I really want is just to create a program that converts numbers in an interval between two decimal numbers  that a person scanf to a list of binary numbers that are in that interval.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question, so I'll drop some hints.

You already have the binary representation, you just need to construct a number from it. Say you have `10110`, the `int` would be `1*(10^4) + 0*(10^3) + 1*(10^2) + 1*(10^1) + 0*(10^0)`.

But note that this might cause you to overflow the `int` range.

To overcome this, store the number in the array as is, and create a special printing function that prints out the binary representation. The advantage of this is that you don't overflow anything as long your array is big enough.

A simpler but slightly involved technique is to just exploit the fact that computers store numbers in binary. To get the k-th bit (from the *right*) of a number, all you need to do is `num & (1<<(k-1))` (which returns 0 if the bit at `k` is zero, non zero if the bit is 1).
Example, for the number `10110` (22 in decimal), `22 & (1<<4)` would be non zero, meaning that the 5th bit from the right is 1. Similarly, to check the 2nd bit (from the *right*), `22 & (1<<1)` returns a non-zero number, meaning that place is 1.